# Vim: change a function's call-signature througout the code-base

Tags: python, vim, command-line, ide, vim-plugin

I'm slowly turning Vim into my IDE-of-choice, with ctags and static-analysis/autocompletion/etc plugins (e.g. vim-jedi, youcompleteme, etc). But I haven't found anything that can do one specific task:

Say I have a function (I'll use Python here):

```
def my_function(outFile, foo, bar):
  outFile.write(foo[bar])
```

Later I change its signature so the outFile positional-argument is a named one:

```
def my_function(foo, bar, outFile=None):
  if outFile is None:
      outFile = getDefaultOutfile()
  outFile.write(foo[bar])
```

Now I want to change all of the old calls, thoughout the entire codebase:

```
my_function(oF, f, b)
```

to

```
my_function(f, b, outFile=oF)
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Vim (or other Linux utils e.g. sed)? I know PyCharm etc can do this, but I'm not intending to jump ship just yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this following regex substitution:

```
:s/\vmy_function\((\w*), (\w*), (\w*)\)/my_function(\2, \3, outfile=\1)/g
```

Read up on [vimregex](http://vimregex.com), specifically capturing groups. Basically, whatever `(\w*)` matches will be saved and named `\1` (then `\2`, `\3`, etc.) for us to use in the replacement later.

It's worth noting that this works for your example, but will not work if there's extra or missing spaces. To make this more robust, you could change it to:

```
:s/\vmy_function\((\w*),\s*(\w*),\s*(\w*)\)/my_function(\2, \3, outfile=\1)/g
```

Comment: Assuming that the code-base consists of more than one file, using this solution you'd probably want to recursively find .py filetypes from the root of the codebase and load each into a vim buffer with `vim $(find -r -type f -name "*.py")`, and then execute the above regex in each buffer using `bufdo`. You could do this in one line using the `-c` flag: `vim -c "bufdo :s/\vmy_function\((\w*),\s*(\w*),\s*(\w*)\)/my_function(\2, \3, outfile=\1)/g" $(find -r -type f -name "*.py")`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `find` (described in an earlier comment), one can also use `grep` to open the files containing the desired function:

```
vim `grep -l 'my_function' *py`
```

The files will be loaded in different buffers. Then use a general buffer replacement:

```
bufdo %s/\(my_function\)(.*)/\1(f, b, outFile=oF)/gc
```

The `c` flag here is optional but I would recommended for this particular replacement.